# Explanation of phrase relating to tyre tread depth

Tags: tires, maintenance, safety

The highway code states that 'Cars, light vans and light trailers must have a tread depth of at least 1.6 mm across the central three-quarters of the breadth of the tread and around the entire circumference.'
(See [this](https://www.gov.uk/vehicle-maintenance-safety-security) if necessary.)

I do not fully understand this statement.
In particular, what does 'the central three-quarters of the breadth of the tread' mean, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the tire straight on so you are looking at the tread (cannot see the rim). Look at the central 3/4 of the tire (~1/8th of the tire's edges on either side). This is the central 3/4 of the breadth of the tire. The tread in this area must be at least 1.6mm deep across this entire width, going all the way around the tire. This would include where the wear ribs are (small raised portion of rubber at the base of the tread). If the ribs are flush with the tire tread across any part of the tire, the tire needs to be replaced. Here's a graphic to help you. This is an approximation, but between the red lines:

[image]

**EDIT:** Look for these on the tire for the wear ribs (bars):

[image]

Comment: What does 'If the ribs are flush with the tire tread' mean, please?

Comment: @CalebOwusu-Yianoma - See edit.

Comment: Alright.  I will do so.

Comment: I recently argued and lost  during my annual inspection over the wear bar issues. In some locales it is interpreted to mean all areas must have 3/32" (1.6mm?) of tread  including  over the wearbars.

Comment: @mikes - 3/32" is actually 2.3813mm ... wondering where the 1.6mm comes from, lol! Anyway you look at it, it's not a lot of tread.

Comment: @Paulster2 1.6mm is the UK legal minimum - and as the OP mentions the Highway Code, I'd guess he is here.

Comment: @NickC - I got that ... again, my humor does not transcend the internet.